# Wireless interruptions on router cause by home laptop sever

Tags: wireless, laptop

Ubuntu home server on laptop/wireless, when accessing the the database from another wireless laptop or desktop such as www.example.com/phpmyadmin, it causes wireless internet to be delay and broken frequently. I have had updated and upgraded this OS to the latest version and it's still doesn't help.

On a desktop it seems to be fine.

I'm thinking of switching from wireless to wire, how do you do it on the Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Switching from wireless to wired is fairly easy to do.

1. Turn off or remove your wireless card.
2. Plug in the wired connection
3. Click on the Network icon next to the clock
4. Click on the wired connection that is showing in the wired section of the dropdown menu.
5. add your username and password
6. Done

Hope this helps